# How to create a virtual machine from a linux file system folder

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, filesystems

I have a Linux file system folder that I got from a dashcam's firmware update archive. It is basically a classic Linux file system (I think it's a Gentoo-based distro, called HiLinux) with opt, etc, usr, boot and other folders, with its own init.d config, etc.

I need to debug a custom firmware I am to create that will be based on that snapshot I've extracted. I want to set up the debugging environment in a VM, install Dropbear (ssh for low power devices), and manage the image via it.

Is there a way I can create a VM image starting solely with Linux fs folder? If yes, could you please outline the general steps on how to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do realize the firmware is most likely expected to run on a ARM/MIPS embedded device, right?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17674

Comment: @DanielB, thanks. I didn't realize virtualizing the hardware that the given OS snapshot is built for will be the main pain point. I think it's not worth it going the VM route.

Comment: QEMU can do emulation, including ARM.  https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#QEMU-System-emulator-for-non-PC-targets